# getting attribute from DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using this [jQuery star rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing) and I would like to get the name of the star that I clicked. The code can be fiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/9343/). How can I get the name of the element that is clicked?

Comment: try checking the view -> source of the page to check what is rendered corresponding to the stars for your plugin...

Comment: I can't get the callback to fire at all, whatever I place in it...

Comment: Your `js` file in the Resource section is executing the executing the `rating()` function before. Check this fiddle out to see the problem.
    http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2xF/

Comment: I fixed the link tot he correct fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.star').click(function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
     });
});
```

**PROTIP:** You should probably give each of your stars a unique ID so you actually know what is being clicked.

Comment: actually this is inside fancybox, so when I do that I get the fancy box name

Comment: Then manipulate it to descend into the children to find the element you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry but he was executing the function before and so it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that rating plugin creates it's own 'stars' to replace the ones you have in your original HTML, and they do not have the same `name` attribute.

Comment: so I have to use a different classname? the question is how do I get the name

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. The script you included in the Resource Section was executing the function before, that's why it was rejecting the execution of the same function double time. Below is the link to your solution. See no changes at all and you can do whatever you want with the function variables `value` and `link`!

**[SOLUTION-1](http://jsfiddle.net/SxqnQ/)**

**[SOLUTION-2](http://jsfiddle.net/yFzgL/)**

Comment: I have a fancybox with an I frame, your solution uses  alert($(this).attr('name'));, in my case, it returns the fancybox name... how do I iterate down to the star?

Comment: Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yFzgL/ 
(Scroll to left and click on any star you want!)
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

there you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/7mY7w/

```
$('.star-rating-control a').live('click.app',function() {
    var parent_classes = $(this).parent('div').attr('class');
    console.log(parent_classes);
    var arr = parent_classes.split(" ");
    var rater = arr[1];
    console.log( rater );
    var rating = $( "." + rater + ".star-rating-on" ).length;
    console.log(rating)
    alert( rater + " has a rating of " + rating  );

    // save in database
    var toBeSaved = rater + '-' + rating; // ex.: rater-1-4

    // or 
    var group = rater.split("-")[1];
    var stars = rating;

});
```

Comment: the stars actually don't have a name but the combination of 'rater' (group of stars) plus 'rating' (selected star) should help

Comment: I actually want to get the name.. as I will use this as an id to post into the db

Comment: you could save the selector: var toBeSaved = rater + '-' + rating; (rater-1-4)